# Sharepoint 2007 - Webpart - Add New Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, webpart

We are using SharePoint Server 2007 to maintain a calendar. There is a view that contains a webpart (Agenda, see picture) with a 'Add New Item' (Nieuw Item Toevoegen) button.

On the left side, you will see a list of dates. When we select a date, eg. 10/12/2013 and click 'Add New Item' below, the new Item isn't added to this date, but to the date closest to the current date of today.

This ONLY happens in Internet Explorer (8, 9, 10). In FireFox/Chrome, the item is added to the correct date.

I'm not a SharePoint hero so I have no clue where to start. Can I change/check this behaviour somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like SP3 for Sharepoint solved this problem.